# How to connect to redux store from react-router onEnter hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux

I'd like to use react-router's `onEnter` hook to check a variable in my redux store when the route loads.

According to the docs, `onEnter`:

> ...receives the next router state as its first argument. The `replaceState` function may be used to trigger a transition to a different URL.

No store passed. Is it possible to connect to the redux store from within this hook? I've tried all sorts of things but cannot find a way to achieve this.

Versions I'm using:

```
"react-redux": "^4.0.0",
"react-router": "1.0.0-rc1",
"redux": "^3.0.0",
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make you routes a function that takes the store in parameter

```
export default (store) => {
 return (
  <Route handler={App} path="/">
    <Route path="mypath" component={handler} onEnter={myHook(store)}>
  <Route>
 )
};
```

Do the same in your transition hook

```
export const myHook = (store) => {
  return (location, replaceWith) => {
    // Do something with your store
  }
};
```

Then assuming your create your store and your router in the same file

```
const router = (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Router history={history}>
                    {routes(store)}
                </Router>
            </Provider>
        );
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. Using RR v 2.0.0-rc5, if I have this (sorry for formatting): `   <Router routes={routes()} history={browserHistory} />`, and then routes looks like this: `export default (props) => {
 return [
  { path: "/", component: AppWrapper}
]};`...then I get this in the console: `Warning: [react-router] You cannot change <Router routes>; it will be ignored`. Am I doing something stupid (and, hopefully, easily correctable)?

Comment: Can you point me to a more complete example.( gist maybe )
 If I remember correctly the warning occurs if your Router component is rerendered.

Comment: Okay, wait, I think I mis-read your example. I don't have a gist at the moment (can make one if need be), but what I was trying to do was to pass the output of the Redux store down to the Router, rather than passing the "store" object itself. In the former case, that triggers (I'm pretty sure) re-render events on <Router>, which RR doesn't seem to like. In the latter case, you have access to the store, and then from within `onEnter()`, you would do `store.getState()` to get the current Redux app state.

Comment: Yes that is the idea, everytime the router calls the onenter method you call getstate on the store to read the current state

Comment: Nothing but a hack. Don't they provided some elegant ready solution for this? It isn't ok if one has to make workarounds.

Answer (score 4):

You might create file store.js and export final store (the same you pass to redux)

E.g.

```
import configureStore from 'utils/configure-store.js';

const store = configureStore();
export default store;
```

and then import to your router file and read state by `store.getState()`

Answer (score 1):

Version 4 of React Router [migration documentation](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/migrating.md#on-properties) recommends using your component lifecycle methods to handle changes.

For example use `componentWillMount` instead of `onEnter` or respond to changes of state via `componentWillReceiveProps`.

So in your component itself:

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';

...

componentWillMount() {
  if (someConditionIsTrue) {
    browserHistory.push('/your/new/path');
  }
}
```

For bonus points you could write this as a [Higher Order Component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html) that simply wraps your original component. Making it easier to share this logic among any other components that require the same behaviour.